# Как настроить Vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Подскажите, как я могу добавить в Vim свои сочетания клавиш, к примеру, хочу при нажатии сtrl+вackspace удалять слово слева от курсора.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать команду map или imap (в зависимости от того, в каком режиме должна работать команда). Скорее всего вот так будет как раз хорошо

```
" Map Ctrl-Backspace to delete the previous word in insert mode.
imap <C-BS> <C-W>
```

Детали - https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word